# create primary key on existing table with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As part of a migration project, we have imported data from a JDE iSeries DB2 database. An SSIS package was created to create the destination tables and import data. The import went successfully.

Now comes the problem - The customer wants Primary Keys created in the destination DB (SQL 2008 R2). The problem table in this case, would be one table that has 104 columns and 7.5 million rows of data. The PK required for this table is composite and has 7 columns.

We are considering this :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F0911] ADD  CONSTRAINT [F0911_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [GLDCT] ASC,
        [GLDOC] ASC,
        [GLKCO] ASC,
        [GLDGJ] ASC,
        [GLJELN] ASC,
        [GLLT] ASC,
        [GLEXTL] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
COMMIT
```

or this:

```
-- Rename existing tables
        sp_RENAME '[F0911]' , '[F0911_old]'
        GO

    -- Create new table
        SELECT * INTO F0911 FROM F0911_old WHERE 1=0
        GO

    --Create PK constraints
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F0911] ADD  CONSTRAINT [F0911_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [GLDCT] ASC,
            [GLDOC] ASC,
            [GLKCO] ASC,
            [GLDGJ] ASC,
            [GLJELN] ASC,
            [GLLT] ASC,
            [GLEXTL] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO

    --Insert data into new tables
        INSERT INTO F0911
        SELECT * FROM F0911_old
        GO

    -- Drop old tables
        DROP TABLE F0911_old
        GO
```

Which would be a more efficient approach, performance wise? I have a gut feeling that both are the same and even the first approach does the same thing as the second one does, implicitly. Is this understanding correct?

Please note that all these columns already exist in the table and we cannot modify the table definition.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I don't see the point of the second approach, apart from the data cleansing. I would have created the new table with the PK to begin with and would insert using a `WHERE` clause that includes the PK fields (in order).

Comment: In any case, adding a 7 field PK on a table with 7.5 million rows will take time and will lock the table - I would take the DB offline to do this work as part of maintenance.

Comment: If you mean what would be more efficient in terms of the end result - yes both will result in identical performance. If you are talking about the _creation_ of the PK, that's a different issue.

Comment: True. The import from DB2 is already done and reimporting is not an option. Amends have to be made to the destination SQL table to include the PK.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but thank you for helping me define a primary key for the F0911 table :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the same. The effect of creating a clustered index is to arrange the pages which will happen in both cases. For non-clustered indexes it will help to disable the index and then turn it back on and rebuilding it.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought. Since the destination DB is still in development, I can afford to take it down if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first approach is right, but I don't understand the reason of BEGIN Transaction and END transaction. I don't think Transaction keyword is necessary because you are not modifying data of the table. Transaction is used where we have to lock the data and we are modifying real time data so the old data is not used.